# in postgresql wire protocol, how can I reach ReadyForQuery from a partially executed select?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to debug an issue with the `node-pg-cursor' module in node.js against a postgresql server (version 9.3)

This module allows for sequential reads of N rows in a select and works by sending

```
cur.read(N): 'Execute' on portal=unnamed, rows=N
```

this command fetches up to N rows and we can continue fetching rows incrementally until the end, where we receive

```
CommandComplete
ReadyForQuery
```

Now my problem is that I want to bail out of the extended command before fetching all the rows and reaching the end of the Execute sequence: I would like to incrementally fetch N rows, N rows, N rows,.. and at one point decide that I have enough.

When I do that (stop fetching via Execute), the query seem to never reach CommandComplete or ReadyForQuery. This seems normal since nothing tells the extended query that I am never going to ask rows from it again.

Apart from closing the connection, is there a command to reach CommandComplete, or ReadyForQuery while not fetching all the rows from the portal ?

I tried to send Close and received CloseComplete, but it did not go to ReadyForQuery.

If I force an ErrorResponse by sending garbage on the protocol, I reach ReadyForQuery but that does not seem very clean ...

Comment: Excellent question (though in future, always include your version numbers please). If you establish a second connection and execute `select pg_cancel_backend($pid_of_first_backend)` where `$pid_of_first_backend` is obtained from `pg_stat_activity` or a `select pg_backend_pid()` before running the query, does that end the result stream in the desired manner?

Comment: Personally I think you'll want to be doing incremental fetches from the portal - ask the server for a certain number of results, read them, decide if you need more.

Comment: If I understand what you say with 'incremental fetches', I think that it is already what I am doing, by sending Execute many times for fetching 100 rows each time. The problem is when I decide that I don't need more ; I need a way to reach ReadyForQuery again on the same connection. I haven't tried pg_cancel_backend yet ; will keep you posted.

Comment: note: the pg_cancel_backend does not end the result stream in the desired manner. In fact, the pg_cancel_backend seem to not cancel the query. in pgadmin I can still see the query as 'active' even after canceling

Comment: OK, so you're sending an `Execute` with a row-count limit, you're getting a `PortalSuspended` response, and you want to abort the rest of the query instead of having to `Execute` and read more rows until you get `CommandComplete`. right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're referring to this, [in the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/protocol-flow.html):

> If `Execute` terminates before completing the execution of a portal (due to reaching a nonzero result-row count), it will send a `PortalSuspended` message; the appearance of this message tells the frontend that another Execute should be issued against the same portal to complete the operation. The `CommandComplete` message indicating completion of the source SQL command is not sent until the portal's execution is completed. Therefore, an `Execute` phase is always terminated by the appearance of exactly one of these messages: `CommandComplete`, `EmptyQueryResponse` (if the portal was created from an empty query string), `ErrorResponse`, or `PortalSuspended`.

Presumably, you're getting `PortalSuspended` and you want to discard the portal without executing any more of it or consuming any more results.

If so, I think you can just send a `Sync` message:

> At completion of each series of extended-query messages, the frontend should issue a Sync message. This parameterless message causes the backend to close the current transaction if it's not inside a BEGIN/COMMIT transaction block ("close" meaning to commit if no error, or roll back if error). Then a ReadyForQuery response is issued.

You may wish to issue a `Close` against the portal first:

> The Close message closes an existing prepared statement or portal and releases resources.

so what I think you need to do is, in message flow terms:

- `Parse`
- `Bind` a named portal
- `Describe`
- Loop:

  - `Execute` with rowcount limit to fetch some rows
  - If no more rows needed; then

    - `Close` the portal
    - Break out of the loop
  - If `CommandComplete` received:

    - Break out of the loop
- `Sync`
- Wait for `ReadyForQuery`

Comment: spot on ! I had tried variants of this but to no avail. a single 'sync' effectively works and I get a ReadyForQuery. Before that I had tried a sequence close + sync but it did not work. It led me to a problem I think in the pg.js library because the "CloseComplete" message is not implemented and it seems to block the sync from happening. After adding an implementation for "CloseComplete" it works I get "CloseComplete" and then "ReadyForQuery". THANK YOU VERY MUCH Craig

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER You're welcome. I learn a lot from this kind of question too; it forces me to dig into bits of Pg I haven't yet done much with on the source code level.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to be using [the asynchronous query processing API](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-async.html), if your driver is a `libpq` wrapper. If it's a native implementation the source code for `libpq` may offer you clues.

Overall, it looks like you'll need to cancel the query using a new connection, then continue to consume input until the buffer is empty. You'll receive however much result data was buffered, then an error message indicating the query was cancelled (if it didn't buffer all its output before you cancelled it) and finally a ReadyForQuery.

I quote [the `libpq` manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-async.html):

> A client that uses PQsendQuery/PQgetResult can also attempt to cancel a command that is still being processed by the server; [see Section 31.6](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-cancel.html). But regardless of the return value of PQcancel, the application must continue with the normal result-reading sequence using PQgetResult. A successful cancellation will simply cause the command to terminate sooner than it would have otherwise.

Systems usually have quite big TCP send buffers, and they're typically dynamic. See [Linux's `tcp(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html), the `SO_SNDBUF` option to `setsockopt(2)`, etc. So quite a lot of data might be buffered before the PostgreSQL server blocks on writing to the socket. PostgreSQL doesn't offer per-connection control of the send buffer size, or even a global config option; you must do it on the operating system level. (That said, it'd be trivial to patch PostgreSQL to set a send buffer size with `setsockopt` and `SO_SENDBUF` if you wanted to).

PostgreSQL can't just flush the output buffer when you cancel a query. Even if it were safe to do so and the platform supported it, Pg doesn't know for sure that the buffer has emptied of results from prior queries and other relevant messages, since you might have piplined multiple queries.

So all you can really do is reduce the maximum size of the TCP output buffer. That'll reduce the amount of data you must read and throw away, but it may impact the performance of other queries that send bulk data.

Instead of trying to run the query and cancelling it when you've seen enough, I suggest reading rows in batches, requesting a new batch when you've consumed the current one. You can do this by using protocol-level cursors. That way you can control how much data the server queues up and you don't have to mess with buffer sizes. You may already be doing this - using a named portal, and sending an `Execute` with a maximum row-count, waiting for the `PortalSuspended` to say there are more rows to read.

Comment: the binding I use is `pg.js` which is a pure js implementation not using libpq. I have to test "canceling + consuming until I get the cancellation message" ; this is a bit more convoluted to setup with an out of band cancel !

Comment: If I 'cancel' on another connection (result = true) and then read incrementally from the original connection, I get the remaining rows up until the end (no cancelation whatsoever). I need to test with a bigger table to see if this is because the rows have already been all prepared on the server. That could explain why the cancel seem to do nothing

Comment: @JeromeWAGNER Yep, most likely it's already been buffered. You may wish to set a smaller send buffer on the server, though this can affect other queries. AFAIK there's no way for the server to flush its send buffer even if it were safe to do so.

Comment: ok I tried with a bigger table and got a weird result (weird to me) : if, when I have decided that I don't want any more rows, I 'Execute rows=0' (meaning fetch all remaining rows) and then cancel, the cancellation works. BUT if I cancel and then 'Execute rows=0', the cancel does not work and I get all the rows. A bit like if the cancelation was only possible in a certain phase of the extended query sequence (?#)

Comment: Regarding your last remark "using a named portal, and sending an Execute with a maximum row-count, waiting for the PortalSuspended to say there are more rows to read" yes this is exactly what I am doing. The problem is that "PortalSuspended" is just a pause ; the query never reaches "ReadyForQuery" and I am looking for a way to force a transition from "PortalSuspended" to "ReadyForQuery", effectively saying "I won't fetch more rows from the portal" + in the state "PortalSuspended", it seems that the cancelation request does nothing at all